# How to skip a matched result of a subquery?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Using sqlite3, I have a table that looks like this:

```
+---------+-----------------+----------+-----------+--------+
| ArtId   |    Location     | ArtistID |  Title    |  Size  |
+---------+-----------------+----------+-----------+--------+
|  3      |      China      |   400    |   birds   | small  |
|  4      |      Samoa      |   670    |   stars   | large  |
|  5      |      Chile      |   427    |   clouds  | medium |
|  6      |        US       |   427    |   clouds  | small  |
|  7      |      France     |   123    |   collage | small  |
|  8      |      Spain      |   123    |   collage | large  |
|  9      |     Belarus     |   123    |   collage | medium |
+---------+-----------------+----------+-----------+--------+
```

I have a query that produces all the results where the only results are ones with duplicate titles and artists:

```
SELECT * 
FROM LiveArt c1, (SELECT Title, ArtistID FROM LiveArt GROUP BY Title, ArtistID) c2 
WHERE c1.Title = c2.Title AND c1.ArtistID = c2.ArtistID
```

to produce the following table:

```
+---------+-----------------+----------+-----------+--------+
| ArtId   |    Location     | ArtistID |  Title    |  Size  |
+---------+-----------------+----------+-----------+--------+
|  5      |      Chile      |   427    |   clouds  | medium |
|  6      |        US       |   427    |   clouds  | small  |
|  7      |      France     |   123    |   collage | small  |
|  8      |      Spain      |   123    |   collage | large  |
|  9      |     Belarus     |   123    |   collage | medium |
+---------+-----------------+----------+-----------+--------+
```

What I want returned is this:

```
+---------+-----------------+----------+-----------+--------+
| ArtId   |    Location     | ArtistID |  Title    |  Size  |
+---------+-----------------+----------+-----------+--------+
|  6      |        US       |   427    |   clouds  | small  |
|  8      |      Spain      |   123    |   collage | large  |
|  9      |     Belarus     |   123    |   collage | medium |
+---------+-----------------+----------+-----------+--------+
```

How can I tweak my query to do that (skip the first matched result)?

Comment: Define "the first matched result."  SQL works in terms of sets, and there is no notion of ordering on a set.  Do you want to skip the matched result with the lowest ArtId value?

Comment: And why isn't the `ArtId=9` skipped?

Comment: @AdamMihalcin, I understand that.  I basically want one of the duplicates left out/skipped.  I don't really care which one, so I thought it might makes sense to skip the first duplicate and select the rest.

Comment: @ypercube, maybe my English is off but I want ArtID records 5 and 7 not selected as they are the first of duplicate records.  I want all other duplicates to be selected.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Do you want the max ArtId for each ArtistId to be returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from tabName A
where A.ArtId !=
(
    select min(ArtId)
    from tabName B
    group by Title
    having A.Title=B.Title
);
```

---

```
ArtId       Location    ArtistID    Title       Size
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
6           US          427         clouds      small
8           Spain       123         collage     large
9           Belarus     123         collage     medium
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c1.* 
FROM LiveArt c1
WHERE EXISTS 
      ( SELECT *
        FROM LiveArt c2
        WHERE c1.ArtID < c2.ArtID 
          AND c1.Title = c2.Title 
          AND c1.ArtistID = c2.ArtistID
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a more efficient way, but something like this might solve the problem for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM LiveArt c1, 
(
  SELECT Title, ArtistID 
  FROM LiveArt 
  GROUP BY Title, ArtistID
) c2
WHERE c1.Title = c2.Title AND c1.ArtistID = c2.ArtistID 
AND c1.ARTID NOT IN 
( 
  SELECT MIN(ArtID) 
  FROM LiveArt
  GROUP BY Title, ArtistID
)
```

Comment: sorry, just realised it was in sqllite, not sql server. I'm not sure if you can do a subquery in the where clause in sqllite